# PlantUML - Activity diagram : layout with activity labels is too complex, how to simplify?

Tags: plantuml

When using connectors in an activity diagram, the layout is clean.
However, when the connectors are replaced by activity labels, the layout become complex which makes the diagram less readable.

See the example below. Is there a way to make the diagram on the right with the same layout as the left diagram ?

[image: Activity diagram]

Code :

```
@startuml
  if (condition 1) then(yes)
    (1)
    detach
  else(no)
  endif
  if(condition 2) then(yes)
    (2)
    detach
  else(no)
  endif
  if(condition 3) then(yes)
    (3)
    detach
  else(no)
  endif
stop

@enduml
```